# Export to Excel from ASP.NET produces files unreadable with Excel Viewer

Tags: asp.net, html, excel, export-to-excel

I want to output some dynamic data from an ASP.NET website to Excel. I found that the easiest way which does not require to use Excel XML or to install Excel on server machine is to [output data as a table](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/199841/EN-US/) and specify *application/vnd.ms-excel* type.

The problem is when I do so and try to open the file in Excel Viewer, I receive the following error message:

> Microsoft Excel Viewer cannot open
>   files of this type.

Then nothing is opened.

Even an easiest code such as:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Clear();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Example.xls");
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    StringWriter stringWriter = new System.IO.StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter htmlTextWriter = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter);
    dataGrid.RenderControl(htmlTextWriter);
    Response.Write("<html><body><table><tr><td>A</td><td>B</td></tr><tr><td>C</td><td>D</td></tr></table></body></html>");
    Response.End();
}
```

produces the same error.

What can cause such behavior? Is it because the **Viewer** cannot read such files, but full Excel version can?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel reader can only open excel files.  You really aren't exporting it as an excel file, you are exporting it as a csv or html.  It's not the same.

EDIT

Have you tried this [Export to Excel?](http://exporttoexcel.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 2):

You never, ever want to go down the route of installing Excel on the server.  The COM interface can work without the UI, but it's not designed to do, and you can end up with a large number of hung EXCEL.EXE instances on your server if there is an error of some sort.  It also plain doesn't work with IIS 7.5's application pool identites, nor does it work with Server Core.

The ideal solution is to use a third-party component that can build binary (or OOXML) Excel files.  SyncFusion and Aspose are two major vendors of such tools.  You'll end up with files that will work all versions of Excel, as well as in other software such as OpenOffice, Google Docs, Outlook Web App, and so on.

Comment: Correct, but preemptively discouraging that solution is important because a lot of people in this situation take it as the next step after realizing that feeding HTML into Excel has real-world drawbacks.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. In fact, I wanted to implement HTML solution because the scenario is very basic and I assume that every user of the *intranet* website will have full Excel version installed. Another solution which I find smart is to use Excel XML format (Excel **2003**, 2007 and 2010). But it was impossible in the current situation (and more difficult to implement).